# Is there any role of permittivity of medium in finding electrostatic force between two charges in that medium in CGS system?

Tags: electromagnetism, coulombs-law

like from coulombs law,we know electrostatic force, $F=\frac{Qq}{4πεr^2}$ .....in SI System
But in CGS this whole term $\frac{1}{4πε}$ got replaced by 1.,i just want to know like *in SI, for different mediums, we use different values of permittivity to get to the solution.*

*Same case if done in CGS, how the permittivity of medium would effect the solution?*

Like where in the formula we indicate that.
It seems like electrostatic force is medium dependent in SI units and is medium dependent in CGS units.

Answer (score 1):

It's $1/4\pi\varepsilon_0$ that is equals to 1 in cgs units. That leaves $\varepsilon_r$ unchanged, so the force is still reduced by a factor $\varepsilon_r$ in a medium other than the void.